# MySQL InnoDB Stored Procedure ROLLBACK on EXIT HANDLER not removing INSERTS

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, innodb, rollback, mysql-5.7

I'm using MySQL 5.7

I'm facing issues where my Stored Procedure is logging duplicate data.
This is happening as Step 2 is being called, then Step 3 fails, and the data I inserted within Step 2 didn't get rolled back.

Am I missing something? An implicit COMMIT that happens once Step 3 starts, or as Step 2 ends?

Here's an example of the pseudo-code/logic:

````
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;
## Table A
## Step 1: 
UPDATE table_A SET status = 1 WHERE status = 0;
COMMIT;

## Step 2:
INSERT INTO table_MAIN 
(Values)
SELECT FROM table_A WHERE status = 1; 

## Step 3: 
UPDATE table_A SET status = 2 WHERE status = 1;
COMMIT;

## Table B
## Step 1: 
UPDATE table_B SET status = 1 WHERE status = 0;
COMMIT;

## Step 2:
INSERT INTO table_MAIN 
(Values)
SELECT FROM table_B WHERE status = 1; 

## Step 3: 
UPDATE table_B SET status = 2 WHERE status = 1;
COMMIT;

END;```
````

Comment: COMMIT finalizes a transaction and does not start another one. So all your statements after the first COMMIT are autocommitted. And ROLLBACK in your handler rollbacks only the statement which causes SQLEXCEPTION.

Comment: Step 3 fails - does it? update won't 'fail' just because it finds nothing to do. What do you mean by fail and how can I reproduce?

Comment: 'By default, MySQL runs with autocommit mode enabled. This means that, when not otherwise inside a transaction, each statement is atomic, as if it were surrounded by START TRANSACTION and COMMIT. You cannot use ROLLBACK to undo the effect; however, if an error occurs during statement execution, the statement is rolled back.' -  you should review  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html

Comment: @P.Salmon - I believe the fail is happening because of a DEADLOCK on table_A (probably that table is being LOCKED at the same time due to ongoing traffic on it.. and it timed out), so table_A stays LOCKED, and Step 3 fails

Comment: @Akina - sorry, this wasn't clear. 
I have COMMIT after Step 1, and COMMIT after Step 3. I'm under the impression that Step 2 and Step 3 would be a single COMMIT.. so if Step 3 fails, Step 2 gets undone. Am I true on my assumption?

Comment: @P.Salmon - on your second comment.. I've added START TRANSACTION, so autocommit should be disabled, making commits only work whenever I forcefully mention COMMIT, or if there's an implicit COMMIT that happens (with commands such as LOCK TABLE, CREATE TABLE, etc..). Isnt this the case?

Comment: *I have COMMIT after Step 1, and COMMIT after Step 3* This is true... but you have only one `START TRANSACTION;`. It starts before step 1 and finishes by its COMMIT. That's all. No transaction. When you perform INSERT on step 2 this insertion is single transaction which is autocommitted immediately. When you perform INSERT on step 3 this insertion is single transaction again, and it is autocommitted immediately. If this INSERT on step 3 causes an error then this insertion is autorollbacked... but the single-statement transaction of step 2 is already committed, and it won't be rollbacked.

Comment: You must put one more `START TRANSACTION;` before step 2. In this case steps 2 and 3 will be performed in single (second) transaction, and ROLLBACK in the handler will revert the whole transaction.